# Printing array of vectors on c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am trying to print an array of vectors in c++.  The program works when I leave out "const" in the parameter list and the "for each" loop.  When I insert the const type qualifiers, it gives me an error.

Here is my main function with the function call to print list:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";

    std::vector<Employee> employeeList {};

    // Entering employee data 
    buildList(employeeList);


    //print the list of employees.
    printList(employeeList);

    //pause code
    int pause;
    std::cin >> pause;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the print list definition:

```
void printList(std::vector<Employee> &list) {
    //use a for each loop to print each employee
    int index = 0;
    for (auto &element : list) {
        std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout << "Employee: " <<(index+1)<<     std::endl;
        element.printEmployee();
        index++;
    }

}
```

Again, when I place const in the parameter list and the for each loop, it gives me an error.  Why?

Here is an image of the error:

[screen capture of the code giving the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1a8W.jpg)

Comment: It would help your question if you added the exact text of the error. If this is Visual Studio copy the text from the Output Tab and not the Errors List,

Comment: I expect printEmployee() is not declared as `void printEmployee() const;`

Comment: Based on the shown code (which is not sufficient) i would guess the error is ypur compiler telling you that you try to use `Employee::printEmployee()` which you forgot to declare as a `const` function. When an Object is `const`, you have only access to `const` methods of this object

Comment: Thanks.  Adding "const" after "void printEmployee()" made it work.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of `Employee::printEmployee` is incorrect. It must be `void Employee::printEmployee() const` for it to be used in a `const` context.

For future reference, what you are calling a for each loop is called a "range-based for loop" or "range-based for". Calling it a for each loop can be confused with the actual algorithm `std::for_each` and should be avoided.